# how to get client ip address and port in php?

Tags: php, ip, port

How to get client ip  address and port in php ? i need to implement  this to with 
when visitors come with IP and PORT  ?

```
$linebyLine = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - $_SERVER[HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP]";
file_put_contents('visitors.log', $linebyLine . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Answers  As difference

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port is defined in http server (Apache or other and mostly it is 80 or 443)

The php $_SERVER variables you can check at : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I am sure that : REMOTE_ADDR' The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get client IP address and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']` to get port

Comment: $linebyLine = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] - $_SERVER[REMOTE_PORT] ";

Its Done !, Thanks